# Unable to Update an existing JournalEntry

Tags: quickbooks, quickbooks-online, intuit-partner-platform

I tried to update an existing journalentry. I am providing id, latest synctoken and line item details. But it returns an error saying that '**Amount on debits not equal to creditsPlease balance your debits and credits** '. I have checked there is no issue in credit and debit amount. Both are equal.

I do not understand why I am getting this issue?

Comment: can you share the relamId and request/response XMLs here ? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my problem. In my existing journal, the lines are with id 0, 1, 2, 3. But while updating it, I was sending the lines with different ids like 0, 2, 7, 8.

So found the solution, I need to pass exact ids for the lines in a journal entry